# Unable to connect to internet via eth cable

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet

As I unsuccessfully tried to connect my Pi to a new wifi network at work I kind of blow up the "original setting" and i'm however still unable to connect to internet using my pi.
I had the situation where i was able to ping 8.8.8.8 but couldn't load google.com
Here are the content of my etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static 
    address 10.93.128.114
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.93.128.0
    broadcast 10.93.128.255
    gateway 10.93.128.254
```

and /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.93.128.114/24
static routers=
static domain_name_servers=    
static domain_search=
```

route -v :

```
destination -> 10.93.128.0 
gateway -> *
genmask -> 255.255.255.0
```

ifconfig :

```
inet addr:10.93.128.114 Bcast:10.93.128.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Comment: You have **TOTALLY** screwed your network settings. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset `etc/network/interfaces` like original, replace what you have written in this fali with that:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual
```

and also `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` deleting all things regarding `eth0`, basically delete what you have write in your answer

If you want to fix tour configuration, on `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` you can try to add

```
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

because in your configuration there is no DNS

Comment: This bears **NO** resemblance to "original"

Comment: Replacing his `etc/network/interfaces` rows and deleting all things he wrote on `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` these files are like original one, also I think the problem is on the `domain_name_servers` without value

Comment: you were right i just got the right DNS at work today and everything worked fine thx again for help :)

Comment: @Wizkhas if it is the correct answer, you can accept it so your question is marked `answered`

Comment: forgot to do so, thx for reminding me